# Who got up/ did get up?

Tags: american-english

I came across this following sentence as I was making a practice about grammar. " Who got up first this morning?" 
I didn't understand why they used "got up" intead of "did get up". Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

Subject-auxiliary inversion does not apply to questions headed by an interrogative pronoun representing the **subject** of the question, so there is no need for the dummy auxiliary *do*.

> Whom did you get up? ... *Here the interrogative pronoun* Whom *represents the* **object** *of* get, *so* did *is inserted to accomplish inversion with the subject,* you.
>
> Who got up? ... *Here the interrogative pronoun* Who *represents the* **subject** *of* get, *so inversion is not required, and* do *is not inserted to accomplish it.*